# echo php variable inside jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

i have this PHP variable set in joomla 2.5 template file

```
$datestart = date('Y-m-d g:i', strtotime("+1 week"));
$dateend = date('Y-m-d g:i', strtotime("+30 days"));
```

and when i echo this

```
<?php echo json_encode($datestart); ?>
```

inside a php page it works. I'm trying to include this variable inside a jQuery function of the RS Form component

```
$formLayout .= "\n".'<script type="text/javascript" src="'.JURI::root(true).'/components/com_rsform/assets/calbs.js"></script>'."\n";
```

in the .js file i have

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
format: "dd MM yyyy - HH:ii P",
showMeridian: true,
autoclose: true,
startDate: <?php echo json_encode($datestart); ?>,
endDate: <?php echo json_encode($dateend); ?>,
minuteStep: 15,
pickerPosition: "bottom-left"

});
 });
```

But it's not working and shows syntax error for the php echo line. How can i solve this ?

Comment: in js file you can not enter php code.

Comment: what error is it showing ?

Comment: If your JavaScript file is not processed by PHP, then the `<?php ... ?>` won't be replaced. Hence the syntax error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to assign the php values first to js variables in .php file

```
<script>
START_Date='<?php echo json_encode($datestart); ?>';
END_Date='<?php echo json_encode($dateend); ?>';

</script>
```

Now in your js file

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - HH:ii P",
        showMeridian: true,
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: START_Date,
        endDate: END_Date,
        minuteStep: 15,
        pickerPosition: "bottom-left"

    });
 });
```

OR include your js code in your php file then you can directly use php variables inside your js like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - HH:ii P",
        showMeridian: true,
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: '<?php echo json_encode($datestart); ?>',
        endDate: '<?php echo json_encode($dateend); ?>',
        minuteStep: 15,
        pickerPosition: "bottom-left"

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can not use php code in js file.
store value in javascript variable and then use this variable in you jquery function.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store this value into the hidden field and then get it by its id value in to  the .js file.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<input type="hidden" id="startdate" value="<?php echo json_encode($datestart); ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" id="enddate" value="<?php echo json_encode($dateend); ?>"/>



jQuery(function() {
var start = jQuery("#startdate").val();
var end= jQuery("#enddate").val();
 jQuery("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
  format: "dd MM yyyy - HH:ii P",
  showMeridian: true,
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: start,
  endDate: end,
  minuteStep: 15,
  pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you should do it this way:
<?php

$datestart = date('Y-m-d g:i', strtotime("+1 week"));
$dateend = date('Y-m-d g:i', strtotime("+30 days"));

?>

 <input id="datestart" type="hidden" name="datestart" value="<?php echo $datestart; ?>">
  <input id="dateend" type="hidden" name="dateend" value="<?php echo $dateend; ?>">

  <script>
      var datestart = document.getElementById('datestart').value;
       var dateend = document.getElementById('dateend').value;

      jQuery(function() {
jQuery("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
format: "dd MM yyyy - HH:ii P",
showMeridian: true,
autoclose: true,
startDate: datestart,
endDate: dateend,
minuteStep: 15,
pickerPosition: "bottom-left"

});
 });
  </script>
```

Comment: this method worked too but i didn't want to include the hidden input type